# Standard Haskell function :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

I have a function defined

```
maybeToList :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]
maybeToList f x = x : maybe [] (maybeToList f) (f x)
```

This function seems so obvious that I can't believe it is not standard.
Is it defined in some module (I already checked Data.Maybe)?

Comment: `maybeToList` is not the best name, considering that there is already a function with that name in `Data.Maybe`, namely `maybeToList = maybe [] (:[])`.  `unfoldStream` or something maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function isn't in the standard libraries because it's a specialized form of [one that is](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr):

```
unfoldr      :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
unfoldr f b  =
  case f b of
   Just (a,new_b) -> a : unfoldr f new_b
   Nothing        -> []
```

That said, the case where the list elements are the same as the sequence of seed values is common, and it's clumsy to write in terms of just `unfoldr` and other standard functions, so I'm not sure why it's not in the standard libraries as well.

Comment: Thanks man, though I think it might be clearer to define a function than to write `unfoldr (join (,) . foo)` :p.